# How to verify the text of an element inside another element using Javascript for Protractor automation test?

Tags: javascript, html, xpath, text, protractor

I am trying to check the text of this
HTML:

```
<div _ngcontent-vpg-c7="" class="substep"><p _ngcontent-vpg-c7="" class="text-xs mb-0 font-weight-bold-light cursor-pointer">text to check</p></div>
```

I am trying something like this but does not work:

```
await driver.wait(until.elementIsVisible await driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class=\"step\"]")).hasDescendant(await driver.findElements(By.xpath("//p[contains(.,'Inserisci gli obiettivi di business')]")))
{
const elements = await driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class=\"step\"]")).hasDescendant(await driver.findElements(By.xpath("//p[contains(.,'Inserisci gli obiettivi di business')]")))
assert {elements.lenght)
}
```

Comment: "'Inserisci gli obiettivi di business'" doesn't appear in your sample html.

Comment: "text to check" was "Inserire gli Obiettivi di Business" in the original code, I changed it but I forgot to change also in the JS code